# How do I make a Bigquery dataset public using command line tool or Python?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm making an open data website powered by BigQuery. How do I make a Bigquery dataset public using command line tool or Python?

Note I tried to make every dataset in my project public but got an unexplained error. In project permission settings via WebUI under "Add members" I put
allAuthenticatedUsers and did the permission Data Viewer. The error was "Error
Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later."

I wasn't able to find any command line examples for updating permissions. I also can't find a JSON string to pass to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/update

Comment: Does it have to be via the CLI or Python (you can do it easily in the Web UI)?

Comment: @GrahamPolley yes it needs to be pro-grammatical because I'm building a web interface to BigQuery.

Comment: Roger that. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this programatically, you need to use a dataset [patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/patch) request and use the `specialGroup` item with the value `allAuthenticatedUsers`, like so:

```
{  
"datasetReference":{  
  "projectId":"<removed>",
  "datasetId":"<removed>"
},
"access":[  
  ... //other access roles
  {  
     "specialGroup":"allAuthenticatedUsers",
     "role":"READER"
  }
 ]
}
```

**Note**: You should use a read-modify-write cycle as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/api-performance#patch) & [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/api-performance#read-patch-write):

> Note about arrays: Patch requests that contain arrays replace the existing array with the one you provide. You cannot modify, add, or delete items in an array in a piecemeal fashion.